# Android Parse Push Notification not working - "Outdated device"

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, notifications, push

After following this tutorial:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing

and this one:
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

and reading all the related questions on stackoverflow, I still can't figure out why Parse is telling me the devices are all outdated.

Here's the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.myPackage.myApp.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myPackage.myApp.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

...

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService"/>
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver.CustomPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.myPackage.myApp"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE"/>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:myAppAndroidUser" />
```

And the Application looks like this:

```
// Parse config
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "[app key]", "[client key]");
    ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

    ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    ArrayList<String> channels = new ArrayList<>();
    channels.add("global");

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.d("Application", "Subscribed to ParsePush");
        }
    });

    parseInstallation.put("channels", channels);
    parseInstallation.saveInBackground();
```

I'm using Lollipop and Parse 1.9.3

I even see the log statement "Subscribed to ParsePush," so I must be close...

Comment: are you seeing that error in logcat? if you are, then the SDK's open source so you should be able to determine this for yourself by inspecting the code.

Comment: No, you can send a notification from Parse.com, and it's saying that there. It gives you a delivery report and it says 78 devices (many are old installations, at least one is the one I just compiled) all failed to receive the notification because they are "outdated"

The app compiles just fine, Parse just doesn't see it.


In the _Installation table, GCMSenderId, deviceToken, and pushType are all undefined, if any of those shouldn't be...

Comment: Hey @AndrewTorr kindly check your manifest you have not mentioned the proper package name I believe, Change com.myPackage to whatever is your package name in all places

Comment: and are you using android studio ? If yes then you need to remove debug{applicationIdSuffix ".debug"} from your gradle file, First try my 1st hint then try this

Comment: I just changed them to myPackage for posting them on stackoverflow.

And yes, how do I get rid of the debug suffix?

Update: I changed the bolts compile line in my gradle file and it now says "GCM DEVICE TOKEN IS EMPTY" instead of "outdated", so that's progress? I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I finally figured it out, since I got a notification to go through successfully from Parse (FINALLY!)
I replaced the custom receiver (that was part of one of the tutorials) with this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Not totally sure why that worked, but that's what did it, I think.